# Working at home: How to block Lan for office device, should only get internet

Tags: networking, router, lan

I have a laptop from office to work at home.
In my home LAN I have many devices which shares files and I don't want
that the office laptop can access it.

Router B is in bridge modus, but I can change if needed and connect input to Wan instead of LAN.

[image: LAN connection diagram]

Preferred if possible: OFFICE should only have internet access! PC should have access to LAN devices OR at least 1 device before Router B should have access to a shared folder on PC.

If not possible: Block OFFICE and PC from LAN, but give them internet.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are required:

- You will need to enable VLAN on the switch in order to isolate the PC and the office device. If this is not possible you will need to connect Router B directly to Router A.
- Router A must be capable to isolate the connection for Router B (e.g. via guest network setting). If this is not possible you could setup a new subnet on your Router B using NAT. It's not a perfect isolation (depends on the specific devices) but it should do the trick for most scenarios.

Comment: Switch does not have VLAN. Router A does not have gues network setting.

Comment: Switch does not have VLAN. Router A does not have guest network setting. So, i have to go with NAT. So steps will be: 1. Connect Router B (WAN or LAN Port?) directly to Router A. 2. Router B (Bride or Router Modus?) enter the NAT Rule for OFFICE? Is sharing between PC and Laptop then still available?

Comment: @mattis you don't need a "NAT rule" (I assume you mean port forward) unless you want to access you office device FROM the internet. Sharing between laptop and pc will be available, yes. about your setup-questions: 1. WAN of Router B to LAN of Router A 2. Router mode (in bridge mode the NAT is usually turned off)

Comment: No access from internet to OFFICE needed. Ok, WAN to LAN and Router B set to Router mode. What i have to do next on which Router, that i can share between Laptop and PC but deny OFFICE to access Laptop, etc but give internet access?

Comment: @mattis you have to set your router that it receives internet connection setup from a DHCP server.

Comment: @mattis If the answer solved your problem, it would be nice if you could accept it (you could write your own answer if you used a different solution).

Answer (score -1):

I have a Private Internet Access VPN subscription and I'm pretty sure there's a checkbox in the program settings to "allow LAN traffic". May be worth a look for an easy solution.